# Concurrently downloading files in python using multi process

Tags: python, concurrency, download, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have made a code below to download files using pySmartDL. I would like to download more than one file at a time. Tried to implement it using multi process. But second process starts only when first finishes. Code is below:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process
from pySmartDL import SmartDL, HashFailedException    
def down():
    dest='/home/faheem/Downloads'
    obj = SmartDL(url_100mb_file,dest, progress_bar=False,fix_urls=True)
    obj.start(blocking=False)
    #cnt=1
    while not obj.isFinished():
            print("Speed: %s" % obj.get_speed(human=True))
            print("Already downloaded: %s" % obj.get_dl_size(human=True))
            print("Eta: %s" % obj.get_eta(human=True))
            print("Progress: %d%%" % (obj.get_progress()*100))
            print("Progress bar: %s" % obj.get_progress_bar())
            print("Status: %s" % obj.get_status())
            print("\n"*2+"="*50+"\n"*2)
            print("SIZE=%s"%obj.filesize)
            time.sleep(2)

    if obj.isSuccessful():
            print("downloaded file to '%s'" % obj.get_dest())
            print("download task took %ss" % obj.get_dl_time(human=True))
            print("File hashes:")
            print(" * MD5: %s" % obj.get_data_hash('md5'))
            print(" * SHA1: %s" % obj.get_data_hash('sha1'))
            print(" * SHA256: %s" % obj.get_data_hash('sha256'))
            data=obj.get_data()
    else:
            print("There were some errors:")
            for e in obj.get_errors():
                    print(str(e))
    return
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #jobs=[]
    #for i in range(5):
    print 'Link1'
    url_100mb_file = ['https://softpedia-secure-download.com/dl/45b1fc44f6bfabeddeb7ce766c97a8f0/58b6eb0f/100255033/software/office/Text%20Comparator%20(v1.2).rar']
    Process(target=down()).start()
    print'link2'
    url_100mb_file = ['https://www.crystalidea.com/downloads/macsfancontrol_setup.exe']
    Process(target=down()).start()
```

Here link2 starts downloading when link1 finishes, but I need both download to perform concurrently. I would like to implement this method to  perform upto 10 downloads at a time. So is it good to use multiprocessing? 
Is there any other better memory efficient method.
I am a beginner in these codes, so kindly define the answer easily..
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use python module `Thread`. Here is a little snippet on how it works:

```
import threading
import time

def func(i):
        time.sleep(i)
        print i

for i in range(1, 11):
        thread = threading.Thread(target = func, args=(i,))
        thread.start()
        print "Launched thread " + str(i)

print "Done"
```

Run this snippet and you will get a perfect idea on how it works.
Knowing that, you can actually run your code, passing as an argument to the function the `url` to use in each thread.

Hope that helps

Comment: Threading is working fine.. Is it possible to retrieve download status of both downloads separately to a database or something. @Carles Mitjans                   Regards

Comment: Thank you for the answer  It is working very fine. Tried this with two threads which is so perfect. How to stop any specific thread separately without producing any alterations to other threads... Regards

Answer (score 0):

The particular library you're using appears to already support non-blocking downloads so why no just do the following? Non-blocking means it'll run in a seperate process.

```
from time import sleep
from pySmartDL import SmartDL 

links = [['https://softpedia-secure download.com/dl/45b1fc44f6bfabeddeb7ce766c97a8f0/58b6eb0f/100255033/software/office/Text%20Comparator%20(v1.2).rar'],['https://www.crystalidea.com/downloads/macsfancontrol_setup.exe']]

objs = [SmartDL(link, progress_bar=False) for link in links]

for obj in objs:
    obj.start(blocking=False)

while not all(obj.isFinished() for obj in objs):
     sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.. But I trying to implement this in torrent download also. And the download links will be added realtime through database input, hence it is not possible to provide the links in advance. I just shown it as an example.. @nico  Regards

Answer (score 0):

Since your program is I/O-bound, you can use multi-processing *or* mult-threading.

Just in case, I'd like to remind the classical pattern for problems like this. Have a queue of URLs from which worker processes / threads pull URLs for processing, and have a status queue where the workers push their progress reports or errors.

A thread pool or a process pull greatly simplifies things, compared to manual control.

Comment: Can you show some examples with code... I cannot get you well. Is it possible to simultaneously call the same function many time as multi process. The system will only have about 1Gb RAM.. Regards @9000